# С чего начать написание тестов для Android приложений?

Tags: android

С чего начать написание тестов для Android приложений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заглянуть на сайт http://developer.android.com/ и ознакомиться с учебником для начинающих "Hello Testing". Это даст начальные знания о тестировании приложений под Android.